# Is it possible to have a login which isn’t an E-mail?

Tags: feature-request, login, email, security

I would like to be able to manage my accounts (private information) independently of my e-mails (public information) because:

- I would like to avoid any sharing of accounts between different servers,
- I would like to manage differently private and public information,
- I would like to be free to change one of them independently of the other.

I am highly demanding in this field to avoid privacy problems and attack exposure (through use of shared and known e-mail to start brute force attacks).

For example, if I was very security aware, and in an ideal world, my Stack Exchange accounts would be something like:

```
acc_SE_dan
acc_SE_test
```

being of course managed by a secure password manager.

Comment: I have a personal domain *example.com* and I use every possible email under that domain for online accounts, like *stackoverflow@exaple.com* and *linkedin@example.com*. They're all forwarded to my real email so I can manage them better.

Comment: Kind of workaround, but gmail allows you to use suffixes in your mail, allowing something like `dan+so@gmail.com` as login, that's still an email, still pointing to your original mail, but usable on only one site

Comment: The enterprise products have SAML as a login option - supporting a subset of those (explicitly) would be nice. Before the openid was depreciated, you could run your own openid endpoint pretty trivially.

Comment: @Tensibai : thank you for this useful information. I am already using this “+” function on my Postfix servers and Gmail. [return] Here my question is about a complete separation of protection and managment of E-mail and accounts. For example, as a consequence of a theft of one of my account (and password) anywhere I would like to ne able to change the stolen account (and password : one uniq user) without touching to my E-mail (a few hundred users).

Comment: Using this method allow you one password per 'alias', using oauth methods makes SO only allowed to read to your Gmail account, hence not saving your password and thus a compromission of SO would only impact SO, that's the main idea behind oauth as far as I know.